# how to set the sftp -s subsystem option in a configuration file

Tags: sudo, openssh, sftp, sshfs

The sftp command supports a subsystem option (-s) which allows the remote user to select the remote sftp-server executable, and optionally upgrade to sudo in the process like so;

```
sftp -s "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
```

This command defers to the ssh client options in ~/.ssh/config allowing the transparent use of pubkey and custom port and user settings.

However `subsystem` appears to be sftp specific, and hence it not set in the config file and it appears it has to be set as a command line option for sftp.

However some tools wrap the sftp invocation so its impossible to set the subsystem option, and hence stuck with user access.

Is there some configuration option file I can use to set this for openssh sftp generally?

is there some configuration file to effect the way gnome nautilus invokes the sftp for its file manager integration?

---

**Update** possible hacky-but-functioning solution is...

So it turns out that there is no obvious config file that sftp will use for options so I ended up modifying a generic wrapper script to add the option explicitly for my selected hosts by putting this in my path;

```
#!/bin/bash
#  Generic shell wrapper that performs an operation

OPERATION=/usr/bin/sftp
args=("$@")
#the final arg should contain a hostname of the form [user@]host[:path]
case "${args[@]: -1}" in
    myserver.com)
    exec $OPERATION -s "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" "$args"
    ;;
*)
   exec $OPERATION "$args" 
    ;;
esac
```

---

**However** depending on your sudoers file, usually to run sudo requires a tty, so you have to pass the "-t" option to ssh, and guess what? there is no configuration option for the ssh client command that is documented that works in the ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config files. haha.

So I write another wrapper script to provide that....

```
#!/bin/bash
#  Generic shell wrapper that performs an operation

OPERATION=/usr/bin/ssh
args=("$@")
#locating the hostname is not so simple with ssh
exec $OPERATION -tt "$args"
```

---

although, I am now having trouble getting the sftp to use my ~/bin/ssh wrapper file, as it appears to be hard coded into sftp and controlled by an option "-S"

Comment: What is your goal? I do not understand any benefit of your command.

Comment: I run the ssh with no root user logins, as per our base build, so it allows sudo users to make changes to files with root permissions via tools that integrate with gnome gvfs.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `ssh_config(5)` man page, you can configure the path in the `sshd_config` configuration file:

```
 Subsystem
         Configures an external subsystem (e.g. file transfer daemon).
         Arguments should be a subsystem name and a command (with optional
         arguments) to execute upon subsystem request.
```

So it looks as if you could simple do this:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -s "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
```

This configuration obviously goes on the *server*, not in the client configuration. Is this what you were looking for?  The downside, obviously, is that *every* sftp connection will attempt to run with root privileges, so this will break non-root access to your files.

Comment: yes, I was looking for something client side. Though I have an idea which I have updated the question with.

Comment: Hmm, I'd really like to have a GUI as well as command line answer. I think that larsks is on the right lines but I think that the subsystem command on the remote server needs to be a script that itself is able either to "know" the rights of the user attempting login, or that is able to gracefully (and silently) fail-back to a standard sftp login.

Comment: Or, of course, I can just use WinSCP on a Windows box!! Seems daft though doesn't it.